# Can you use infinity in a cell reference in LibreOffice (or any other spreadsheat)?

Tags: microsoft-excel, spreadsheet, libreoffice-calc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you reference an entire column in OpenOffice Calc (like A:A in Excel)?](https://superuser.com/questions/160435/can-you-reference-an-entire-column-in-openoffice-calc-like-aa-in-excel)

I'm using a Sum of a column, and it keeps growing, so I have to update the reference to which cells should be summed.
Can you reference an infinite group of cells?
Let's say:
`SUM(D2:D∞)`

No matter if you use LibreOffice, Excel or any other spreadsheet, your solution may be applied to LibreOffice too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Excel the solution is to use a reference to the entire column. While Excel has a limit on the number of rows and columns a sheet can have, the maximum number is as close to infinite as you're going to get.

For your example, you could use the following:

```
=SUM(D:D)-IF(ISNUMBER(D1),D1,0)
```

This adds everything in Column D and subtracts the value of D1, the cell you left out.